# Function returns string when bool is expected

Tags: sml, ml

What's wrong with this piece of code?

`fun expd s:string = if size(s) > 0 then true else false;`

The error I recieve:

```
- fun exnd s:string = if size(s) > a then true else false;
stdIn:657.1-837.8 Error: unbound variable or constructor: a
Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
  expression:  bool
  result type: string
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses around `s:string`, because right now `string` is interpreted as the output type of the function and not the type of the parameter `s`:

```
fun expd (s:string) = if size(s) > 0 then true else false
```

By the way, the compiler can infer all the types here without any type annotations. Try the following:

```
fun expd s = if size(s) > 0 then true else false
```

And, of course, you can simplify this definition into:

```
fun expd s = size(s) > 0
```